# $.getJSON onComplete event doesn't wait for result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm getting an img source list from JSON, and I call the `loadThumbs(json)` event, but it says `json` is undefined I printed it out to the console and it's empty, but if I print it out manually it prints out the JSON object. So the problem is that the `loadThumbs(json)` runs before the `$.getJSON` completed.

```
$.getJSON("api.php?query=references", function(result){
    loadThumbs(result);
    //other code that works fine
});

function loadThumbs(json) {
    preload(json[current].images);
    //other code works fine
}

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code should work. However what is the value of `current`?

Comment: Is `json[current].images` actually set? Or is the images list somewhere else in the tree

Comment: Note that `$('<img/>')[0].src = this;` makes no sense

Comment: `current` is an index just an integer

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to call your function on **.done**. You can try this code

```
$.getJSON("api.php?query=references", function(){

    //other code that works fine
}).done(function( result) {
// call here
loadThumbs(result);
});

function loadThumbs(json) {
    preload(json[current].images);
    //other code works fine
}

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
```

For more information [**click Here**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)